# Status bar changing tint color when navigation bar going to hidden XCode

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, statusbar, tint

I'm using [RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers)

to switch between UIViewControllers by swipe, and it's all good, but here is a some strange thing i stuck with(look at the screen):

I made that if you scroll news feed down - navigation title going to hidden, and here is curious thing happening: when navigation title disappear - Status bar changing tint color to black! I just don't understand how it's possible?

[image]

I already added to to appDelegate

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
```

and

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

to every possible controllers, and of course navigation bar style i set to "black" but alas! Can anyone say me how to fix it? I will be really appreciate about it!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I did was add

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }
```

inside the UIViewController.

This is in swift though. I guess you need to override the function.